# Error al crear proyecto en unreal: Windows SDK 8.1 debe estar instalado

Tags: c++, unreal-engine

Cuando intento crear un proyecto en unreal engine me sale el siguiente error:

> ERROR: UnrealBuildTool Exception: Windows SDK v8.1 must be installed
>   in order to build this target.

¿Por qué ocurre esto y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: ahí dice que el SDK para Windows debe estar instalado, ya lo tienes en tu computadora?

Comment: Habia descargado uno para windows 10 (es la que tengo)

Comment: la versión que te indica el mensaje de error? la 8.1 pudiera ser que descargaste una inferior a esa

Comment: Voy a intentar descargando Windows 10 SDK, version 1803

Comment: Me sigue apareciendo, y no entiendo que le pasa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listo, ya pude, pasa que el engine necesita si o si uno que sea para windows 8.1, entonces simplemente lo descarge aca: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=323507
y funciona bien